# En el file.conf muestra Error usando Supervisor, en digital ocean ¿alguna opcion para corregirlo?

Tags: django, linux, nginx, digitalocean, gunicorn

Al configurar el file.conf
ruta : sudo nano /etc/supervisor/conf.d/facturaempresa.conf

```
[program:facturaempresa]
command=/home/user/bin/gunicorn_start
user=user
autostart=true
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/home/user/logs/gunicorn-error.log
```

Al ejecutar los siguientes comandos

```
sudo supervisorctl reread
sudo supervisorctl update
sudo supervisorctl status facturaempresa
```

la terminal muestra el siguiente error

```
facturaempresa     FATAL     Exited too quickly (process log may have details)
```

Estoy usando Ubuntu 16.04.5 x64, django2.0 con python3 gunicorn nginx en digital ocean,alguna idea para corregir el error en la configuracion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba con está configuración :

```
[program:tos]
command = /home/usuario/gunicorn_start.bash
user = root
stdout_logfile = /home/usuario/logs/gunicorn_supervisor.log
redirect_stderr = true
environment=LANG=en_US.UTF-8,LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

Asegurate de cambiar las rutas.